# Why are Superposition states not solution of TISE?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, superposition

Form a textbook i am learning for its says:

All valid wave functions (energy eigenfunction with definite energy and superposition states with simultaneously multiple energies) for a given quantum system satisfy the Time dependent Schrodinger equation.

However only the spatial parts $u(x)$ of energy eigenfunction [definite energy states with energy $E$ in $T(t)$] solve the Time-independent Schrodinger equitation. Superposition states are not solution of TISE

Can anyone explain why this is case and show me way to prove this mathematically (if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

The TISE is a generic eigenvalue problem:
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}\psi = E \psi
\end{equation}
where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian and $E$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenstate $\psi$.
Now take $\psi_1, \psi_2$ to be 2 eigenstates with eigenvalues $E_1, E_2$, look at the superposition $\psi_1 + \psi_2 = \Phi$:
\begin{align}
\hat{H}(\psi_1 + \psi_2) &= E_1 \psi_1 + E_2\psi_2\\
\Rightarrow \hat{H} \Phi &= E_1 \psi_1 + E_2 \psi_2 \neq E_\Phi \Phi
\end{align}
Clearly $\Phi$ is not an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ unless $E_1 = E_2$.

Comment: isn't the TDSE an generic eigenvalue problem. Can it to bot be give has $\hat{H}\psi=E\psi$. If not how will the TDSE look like in that form

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The TISE is a generic eigenvalue problem, hence providing a basis of eigenvectors for all operators commuting with the Hamiltonian. The TDSE is not an eigenvalue equation, but a differential equation which we solve through separation of variables.